# Changing multiple selection mode for QListView

Tags: qt

In QListView, i'd like to disable mouse drag multiple selection - that is, mous down on a row, drag the mouse down and select the rows below it while dragging.

I'd still like row selection using CTRL-mouse click.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it would be to create a derived class from the QListView and then override its mouseMoveEvent function.  This function in the Qt Code for the QListView looks for a dragging state and creates a rectangle.  I think something like this may work, but I didn't test it:

```
void DerivedListView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    if (state() != DragSelectingState)
        QListView::mouseMoveEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: not really. first touched items get selected when dragging from an empty space...

Answer (score 13):

It seems you've set the list view's selection mode to QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection. Try setting it to QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection with:

```
listView->setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection );
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: `ExtendedSelection` is a superset of `MultiSelection`, so it also selects on click+drag.